# Google Maps JS API V3 addMarker - Markers are Echoed in source, no map

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The code below is supposed to generate a google map and retrieve markers from a MySQL database and plot them on the map. Instead, I get a blank page with no errors, and when viewing source, all the addMarker points are echoed there. What am I doing wrong? I tried moving the php db query section at the end to outside of the JS section and that ended up echoing the addMarker db results to the actual page, not just visible in source.

```
    <?php
$dbname            ='edited out'; //Name of the database
$dbuser            ='edited out'; //Username for the db
$dbpass            ='edited out'; //Password for the db
$dbserver          ='edited out'; //Name of the mysql server

$dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Stott Outdoor Advertising Experimental Inventory Map - SQL Version</title>
<style>
   html { height: 100%; }
   body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
   #map_canvas { height: 100%; }
   </style>

     <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=edited out">
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("edited out/gmaps/Bulletin-sm.png",
 new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(39.729468, -121.847099),
 new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
 var center = null;
 var map = null;
 var currentPopup;
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: info,
 maxWidth: 300
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup = null;
 }
 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
 currentPopup = null;
 });
 }
 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 14,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });
 <? php
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM edited out");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $name=$row['name'];
 $lat=$row['lat'];
 $lon=$row['lon'];
 $desc=$row['desc'];
 echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");
 }
 ?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);

 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
 <div id="map"></div>
 </html>
```

**Update:** Per @gegillam, I added coordinates instead of 0,0 to google.maps.size. Unfortunately, the map is still not displaying. Per @geocodezip, the following is what the browser sees:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Stott Outdoor Advertising Experimental Inventory Map - SQL Version</title>
<style>
   html { height: 100%; }
   body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
   #map_canvas { height: 100%; }
    }
</style>

     <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=edited out">
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("edited out/gmaps/Bulletin-sm.png",
 new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(39.729468, -121.847099),
 new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
 var center = null;
 var map = null;
 var currentPopup;
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: info,
 maxWidth: 300
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup = null;
 }
 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
 currentPopup = null;
 });
 }
 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 14,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });

 center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
  addMarker(41.953133, -124.204185,'<b>2</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 700ft north of Mouth of Smith River Rd');
addMarker(38.162266, -121.26223,'<b>3</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 740ft north of Woodbridge Rd');
addMarker(36.31665, -119.685837,'<b>4</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 198, 2160ft east of 13th Ave Overpass');
addMarker(41.580868, -124.078964,'<b>5</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 20ft north of Lonesome Rd');
addMarker(35.990166, -119.299202,'<b>6</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 1.2 miles south of Ave 120');
addMarker(39.186417, -123.211037,'<b>7</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 1800ft south of Lake Mendocino Dr');
addMarker(39.465332, -121.576866,'<b>8</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 700ft north of Ophir Rd');
addMarker(35.213516, -119.011452,'<b>102</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 1800ft north of Bear Mountain Rd (south of Bakersfield)');
addMarker(39.686066, -122.207436,'<b>103</b><br/>West Side of I-5, 2000ft north of Road 27');
addMarker(39.334435, -121.68335,'<b>201</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 50ft north of Evans Reimer Rd');
addMarker(39.028534, -122.920418,'<b>202</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 29, south of Todd Road Exit');
addMarker(40.421417, -122.282799,'<b>203</b><br/>West Side of I-5, 1.1 miles south of Deschutes Rd Overcrossing');
addMarker(39.341816, -123.315987,'<b>204</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 950ft north of Black Bart Dr (south of Willits)');
addMarker(39.423569, -119.205521,'<b>205</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 50, 800ft west of Orange Ln (1 mile east of Silver Springs)');
addMarker(37.008484, -120.11483,'<b>206</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1 mile south of Avenue 18 1/2 Overpass (north of Madera)');
addMarker(40.424519, -122.283279,'<b>207</b><br/>West Side of I-5, .9 miles south of Deschutes Rd');
addMarker(39.478851, -122.192535,'<b>208</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 1 mile south of Road 57 Interchange');
addMarker(39.339268, -123.31292,'<b>301</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 350ft south of Blackbart Drive');
addMarker(39.356049, -122.192451,'<b>303</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 2650ft north of Delevan Overcrossing');
addMarker(35.990368, -119.959366,'<b>304</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 41, 800ft north of Bernard Dr');
addMarker(39.4202, -123.35508,'<b>305</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 600ft north of Casteel Ln');
addMarker(40.687, -122.345932,'<b>306</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 1450ft north of Union School Rd');
addMarker(41.947834, -124.196533,'<b>307</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 360ft south of Salmon Harbor Rd');
addMarker(35.737118, -119.241386,'<b>308</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 3500ft south of Woollomes Ave');
addMarker(39.378681, -123.339813,'<b>309</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 970ft north of south turn off to Hollands Ln');
addMarker(37.339149, -120.5868,'<b>310</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 2050ft south of East Atwater Overpass');
addMarker(99.554001, -119.26915,'<b>402</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 1150ft west of West Fernley Interchange #46');
addMarker(38.111649, -121.258499,'<b>403</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1650ft south of Kettleman Lane');
addMarker(39.781319, -121.882286,'<b>404</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 1/4 mile north of Eaton Rd');
addMarker(35.990719, -119.298386,'<b>405</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, .88 miles north of Ave 104');
addMarker(39.175781, -121.988716,'<b>406</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 20, 1200ft west of Niagra');
addMarker(39.190132, -121.99688,'<b>407</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 20, 435ft west of Sunrise Blvd.');
addMarker(35.956818, -119.053215,'<b>409</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 65, 1975ft south of Avenue 95');
addMarker(41.6833, -122.632668,'<b>501</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 1 mile south of Yreka');
addMarker(41.93475, -124.169014,'<b>502</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 600ft north of Ocean View Drive');
addMarker(41.952251, -124.203133,'<b>503</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 200ft north of Mouth of Smith River Road');
addMarker(41.95155, -124.202187,'<b>504</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 200ft south of Mouth of Smith River Road');
addMarker(38.768417, -120.44622,'<b>505</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 50, 440ft east of Ice House Road');
addMarker(40.908699, -124.088486,'<b>507</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 1600ft north of Giuntoli Lane');
addMarker(35.955933, -119.053284,'<b>508</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 65, 2300ft south of Avenue 95');
addMarker(41.747551, -124.178818,'<b>601</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 90ft south of Neptune');
addMarker(40.484001, -122.350983,'<b>603</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 273, 900ft north of Overland Drive');
addMarker(40.94685, -117.488518,'<b>604</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 750ft east of Golconda Overcrossing at MP 30.58');
addMarker(40.280418, -120.487129,'<b>605</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 395, 1570ft south of County Rd A-3 (9 miles south of Susanville)');
addMarker(39.026199, -123.137497,'<b>606</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 1320ft north of Largo Rd (Approx 6 miles south of Ukiah)');
addMarker(39.268017, -123.233482,'<b>607</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 3800ft north of West Road');
addMarker(41.431019, -122.389069,'<b>701</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 97, 200ft north of Alamo Avenue');
addMarker(41.471985, -122.351349,'<b>702</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 97, 200ft south of Big Springs Road');
addMarker(41.472832, -122.351135,'<b>703</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 97, 100ft north of Big Springs Road');
addMarker(41.473618, -122.350784,'<b>704</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 97, 420ft north of Big Springs Road');
addMarker(41.474533, -122.350464,'<b>705</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 97, 800ft north of Big Springs Road');
addMarker(41.967232, -121.914146,'<b>706</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 97, 400ft north of Railroad Avenue');
addMarker(41.967182, -121.912933,'<b>707</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 97, 670ft north of Railroad Avenue');
addMarker(41.967201, -121.912514,'<b>708</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 97, 1100ft north of Railroad Avenue');
addMarker(41.967251, -121.912033,'<b>709</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 97, 1260ft north of Railroad Avenue');
addMarker(41.494999, -120.583153,'<b>710</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 299, 2 miles west of Alturas');
addMarker(41.494934, -120.580902,'<b>711</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 299, 1.9 miles west of Alturas');
addMarker(41.500015, -120.530266,'<b>712</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 395, .5 miles north of Alturas');
addMarker(40.468334, -122.328247,'<b>713</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 273, 1150ft south of Hill Street');
addMarker(39.747349, -122.17627,'<b>717</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 32, 300ft east of M Street');
addMarker(40.946815, -117.76255,'<b>718</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 1/2 mile west of Winnemucca Exit 176');
addMarker(40.399734, -122.280418,'<b>719</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 273 (Main St), 1175ft north of Trefoil Lane');
addMarker(36.099682, -119.322365,'<b>720</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1/2 mile south of Tipton Rest Area');
addMarker(33.760799, -116.305229,'<b>721</b><br/>South Side of I-10, .2 miles west of Washington Street Overcrossing');
addMarker(33.917984, -116.773552,'<b>722</b><br/>South Side of I-10, at MP 19.60');
addMarker(35.989265, -119.29805,'<b>723</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, .78 miles north of Ave 104');
addMarker(35.823101, -119.258835,'<b>801</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 1300ft north of Avenue 16');
addMarker(38.137466, -121.253502,'<b>802</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 12 (Victor Rd), 220ft west of Cluff Avenue');
addMarker(38.740501, -122.624817,'<b>803</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 29, 1550ft north of Dry Creek cut off (south of Middletown)');
addMarker(39.424782, -123.354301,'<b>804</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 1/2 mile north of Willits City Limits');
addMarker(35.955067, -119.053253,'<b>805</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 65, 2625ft south of Avenue 95');
addMarker(39.536182, -119.796165,'<b>806</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 1/2 mile west of Hwy 395 Interchange');
addMarker(39.469383, -121.575882,'<b>901</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 70, .41 miles north of Ophir Road');
addMarker(39.470798, -121.576149,'<b>902</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 70, .51 miles north of Ophir Road');
addMarker(39.69915, -122.1968,'<b>903</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 850ft north of County Road 25');
addMarker(39.747215, -122.185532,'<b>904</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 32 (Walker Street), 540ft east of East Street');
addMarker(41.49445, -120.578682,'<b>905</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 299, 1.7 miles west of Alturas');
addMarker(39.751049, -121.904831,'<b>906</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 32, 230ft west of Muir Ave');
addMarker(40.402, -122.281502,'<b>907</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 4200ft north of Gas Pointe Road');
addMarker(41.889084, -121.380585,'<b>1001</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 139, 550ft north of County Road 113');
addMarker(41.888569, -121.379753,'<b>1002</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 139, 250ft north of County Road 113');
addMarker(41.865749, -121.341866,'<b>1003</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 139, 800ft north of County Road 140');
addMarker(41.86525, -121.341331,'<b>1004</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 139, 500ft north of County Road 140');
addMarker(39.487385, -118.874718,'<b>1005</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 50, 150ft east of Roberson Lane');
addMarker(36.151951, -119.075165,'<b>1006</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 65, 265ft south of Avenue 200');
addMarker(38.055382, -121.258751,'<b>1007</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, .14 miles south of Eight Mile Road');
addMarker(40.723083, -122.324615,'<b>1008</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 3000ft south of Fawndale Overcrossing');
addMarker(39.751919, -121.910202,'<b>1107</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 32, .5 miles east of Meridian');
addMarker(39.751999, -121.909866,'<b>1108</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 32, 1/2  and  25ft east of Meridian');
addMarker(39.703999, -121.770836,'<b>1321</b><br/>North Side of Skyway, .6 miles east of Honey Run Rd');
addMarker(39.714951, -121.805984,'<b>1409</b><br/>North Side of Park Ave, 400ft east of Whitman Ave');
addMarker(39.831718, -121.932518,'<b>1506</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1 mile south of Cana Hwy');
addMarker(39.808102, -121.912117,'<b>1508</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 750ft south of Anita Rd');
addMarker(39.795898, -121.902031,'<b>1510</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 200ft south of Wilson Landing Rd');
addMarker(39.798817, -121.904053,'<b>1518</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 750ft north of Wilson Landing Rd');
addMarker(39.784569, -121.886253,'<b>1521</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 3/4 mile north of Eaton');
addMarker(39.764584, -121.861771,'<b>1527</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 1/4 mile north of Lassen Ave');
addMarker(39.721432, -121.805031,'<b>1530</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1500ft south of East 20th St');
addMarker(39.722183, -121.805702,'<b>1537</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1000ft south of East 20th St');
addMarker(39.704666, -121.789413,'<b>1540</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, .2 miles north of Southgate Ln');
addMarker(39.70435, -121.789864,'<b>1546</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, .2 miles north of Southgate Ln');
addMarker(39.695969, -121.779068,'<b>1547</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, .6 miles south of Southgate Ln');
addMarker(39.696667, -121.77977,'<b>1550</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, .5 miles south of Southgate Ln');
addMarker(39.650032, -121.725533,'<b>1551</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, .3 miles north of Pentz Rd');
addMarker(39.653, -121.72805,'<b>1552</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1 mile north of Durham Pentz Rd (10 mile south of Chico)');
addMarker(39.493233, -121.689117,'<b>1554</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, at Hwy 162 Junction');
addMarker(39.342949, -121.686699,'<b>1559</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 150ft south of Township Rd');
addMarker(39.324066, -121.679787,'<b>1562</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 150ft north of Turner (2 miles south of Gridley)');
addMarker(39.755466, -121.860229,'<b>1605</b><br/>West Side of Esplanade, 75ft north of White');
addMarker(39.756367, -121.861717,'<b>1717</b><br/>South Side of East Ave, 100ft west of Esplanade');
addMarker(39.751617, -121.630867,'<b>2155</b><br/>North Side of Skyway, 20ft west of Black Olive');
addMarker(39.750351, -121.607552,'<b>2207</b><br/>East Side of Clark, 400ft south of Pearson');
addMarker(39.460716, -121.581413,'<b>3113</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, .3 miles south of Ophir Rd');
addMarker(39.481731, -121.575218,'<b>3120</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 1000ft north of GP Way');
addMarker(39.478668, -121.57505,'<b>3123</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 300ft north of GP Way');
addMarker(39.474499, -121.575165,'<b>3131</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 1500ft south of GP Way');
addMarker(39.475418, -121.575134,'<b>3140</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 1250ft south of GP Way');
addMarker(39.519932, -121.572868,'<b>3143</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 70, 200ft north of Grand Ave Overpass');
addMarker(39.49205, -121.574783,'<b>3147</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 2750ft south of Oro Dam Blvd Exit');
addMarker(39.492733, -121.574837,'<b>3155</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 2500ft south of Oro Dam Blvd');
addMarker(39.494133, -121.574883,'<b>3160</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 1500ft south of Oro Dam Blvd Exit');
addMarker(39.093418, -121.540916,'<b>4010</b><br/>Junction Hwy 70 and 65 4 miles south of Marysville');
addMarker(39.17915, -121.626579,'<b>5007</b><br/>East Side of Live Oak Blvd, .7 miles south of Eager Rd (1/2 mile north of Yuba City)');
addMarker(40.371601, -122.283981,'<b>6005</b><br/>East Side of I-5, by Cottonwood Bridge');
addMarker(40.286633, -122.278503,'<b>6010</b><br/>West Side of I-5, on Nine Mile Hill');
addMarker(40.04015, -122.099815,'<b>6015</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, at Los Molinos NCL');
addMarker(40.128384, -118.520782,'<b>7001</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 1250ft west of Westfall Rd (3 miles west of Lovelock)');
addMarker(40.12965, -118.521652,'<b>7002</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 1150ft west of Westfall Rd (3 miles west of Lovelock)');
addMarker(40.458267, -118.28495,'<b>7003</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 3200ft west of Rye Patch Exit');
addMarker(40.459801, -118.284798,'<b>7004</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 2600ft west of Rye Patch Exit');
addMarker(40.660282, -118.137367,'<b>7005</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 2600ft east of Imlay Exit');
addMarker(40.660831, -118.13102,'<b>7006</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 4300ft east of Imlay Overcrossing');
addMarker(40.916382, -117.839699,'<b>7011</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 2.28 miles west of West Winnemucca Exit 173');
addMarker(40.916718, -117.837967,'<b>7012</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 2.18 miles west of West Winnemucca Exit 173');
addMarker(40.9174, -117.836365,'<b>7013</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 2.08 miles west of West Winnemucca Exit 173');
addMarker(40.91785, -117.834618,'<b>7014</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 1.9 miles west of West Winnemucca Exit 173');
addMarker(41.155815, -117.686096,'<b>7015</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 95, 3170ft south of Dutch Flat Rd (13 miles north of Winnemucca)');
addMarker(41.156631, -117.685867,'<b>7016</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 95, 3530ft south of Dutch Flat Rd (13 miles north of Winnemucca)');
addMarker(39.4659, -121.548431,'<b>8335</b><br/>North Side of Ophir Rd, 250ft east of Lincoln Blvd');
addMarker(39.510551, -121.487633,'<b>9209</b><br/>North Side of Olive Hwy, 400ft east of Skyline Dr');
addMarker(39.782417, -121.883598,'<b>9210</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, .7 miles north of Eaton Rd');
addMarker(40.185883, -122.189102,'<b>9211</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 36 (Antelope Blvd), 330ft east of St. Marys Ave');
addMarker(39.003601, -121.625336,'<b>9214</b><br/>North Side of Tudor Rd, 1500ft east of Hwy 99 and Hwy 113 Junction');
addMarker(39.744099, -121.888336,'<b>9301</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 32, 300ft south of Kennedy');
addMarker(39.105385, -121.634331,'<b>9303</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1275ft north of Smith Rd');
addMarker(39.100117, -121.634232,'<b>9304</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 665ft north of Bogue Rd');
addMarker(38.903416, -121.543465,'<b>9306</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 70, 120ft south of Palm 1200ft south of E. Nicolaus 4-way stop');
addMarker(39.510784, -121.486748,'<b>9307</b><br/>North Side of Olive Hwy, 700ft east of Skyline Dr');
addMarker(39.503235, -121.527802,'<b>9312</b><br/>South Side of Olive Hwy (Hwy 162), 1275ft east of Foothill Blvd');
addMarker(40.307751, -122.279053,'<b>9314</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 1000ft north of Valley Auction Rd (apprx 9 miles north of Red Bluff)');
addMarker(39.003399, -121.624336,'<b>9315</b><br/>South Side of Tudor Rd, 1600ft east of Hwy 99 and Hwy 113 Junction');
addMarker(40.185532, -122.188431,'<b>9403</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 36 (Antelope Blvd), 525ft east of St. Marys Ave');
addMarker(39.101418, -122.114853,'<b>9405</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 100ft north of Myers Rd (Approx 4 miles south of Williams)');
addMarker(39.148933, -122.138916,'<b>9406</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 2000ft south of E St Exit (Williams Central Exit)');
addMarker(39.171032, -121.984947,'<b>9407</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 20, 600ft east of Niagra');
addMarker(39.288715, -121.665283,'<b>9408</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 1325ft south of Nevada');
addMarker(39.928001, -122.1875,'<b>9411</b><br/>North Side of Solano St (Hwy 99 W), 125ft west of Hoag');
addMarker(39.197132, -122.036331,'<b>9412</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 20, 200ft west of Wilson Ave');
addMarker(39.505066, -121.497818,'<b>9501</b><br/>South Side of Olive Hwy (Hwy 162), 220ft west of Oakvale');
addMarker(39.495701, -122.195099,'<b>9503</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 50ft north of County Road 57');
addMarker(39.022968, -122.916718,'<b>9505</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 29, 4000ft south of Todd Road Exit');
addMarker(38.904083, -122.612617,'<b>9506</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 29, 800ft north of Clayton Creek Rd');
addMarker(39.133781, -122.1362,'<b>9507</b><br/>West Side of I-5, 2000ft north of Husted Rd');
addMarker(39.171932, -121.985802,'<b>9508</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 20, 300ft east of Niagra');
addMarker(39.700066, -121.783485,'<b>9601</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 630ft south of Southgate Ln');
addMarker(40.444599, -122.2892,'<b>9602</b><br/>West Side of I-5, 2600ft north of Deschutes Rd');
addMarker(39.160133, -122.896332,'<b>9603</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 20, 420ft west of Lucerne Rd (apprx 2 miles east of Hwy 29 Junction)');
addMarker(39.112549, -123.195335,'<b>9604</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 200ft north of Treatment Plant Rd');
addMarker(39.182751, -123.211716,'<b>9605</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 3000ft south of Lake Mendocino Dr');
addMarker(39.159569, -122.145203,'<b>9606</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 1000ft north of E St (Business 20) Overcrossing');
addMarker(41.154934, -117.686333,'<b>9607</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 95, 2800ft south of Dutch Flat Rd (13 miles north of Winnemucca)');
addMarker(40.914165, -117.846535,'<b>9608</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 2.67 miles west of West Winnemucca Exit 173');
addMarker(40.913517, -117.848564,'<b>9609</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 2.78 miles west of West Winnemucca Exit 173');
addMarker(39.127384, -122.130569,'<b>9610</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 630ft south of Husted Rd Overpass');
addMarker(39.346401, -121.687881,'<b>9611</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 992ft north of Township Rd');
addMarker(39.196968, -123.20932,'<b>9613</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 580ft south of Parducci Rd');
addMarker(39.266251, -123.23053,'<b>9614</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 2800ft north of West Road');
addMarker(38.557335, -121.676735,'<b>9701</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 3/4 mile east of Mace Rd');
addMarker(38.548916, -121.713997,'<b>9702</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 1 mile west of Mace Rd');
addMarker(39.480831, -118.818367,'<b>9704</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 50, 250ft west of Gummow Dr');
addMarker(38.893131, -122.606621,'<b>9705</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 29, 1650ft north of Spruce Grove Rd');
addMarker(38.907684, -123.055298,'<b>9706</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 101, 6 miles north of Cloverdale');
addMarker(39.434166, -121.604851,'<b>9707</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 200ft north of Palermo Rd');
addMarker(39.435001, -121.604652,'<b>9708</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 70, 500ft north of Palermo Rd');
addMarker(39.184601, -121.993782,'<b>9709</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 20, 175ft east of Farinon Rd (East of Colusa)');
addMarker(39.178398, -121.990265,'<b>9710</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 20, 60ft west of Airport South Gate Rd (East of Colusa)');
addMarker(40.915218, -117.843246,'<b>9711</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 2.48 miles west of West Winnemucca Exit 173');
addMarker(40.915783, -117.841614,'<b>9712</b><br/>South Side of I-80, 2.38 miles west of West Winnemucca Exit 173');
addMarker(38.966148, -122.025665,'<b>9713</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 80ft north of Green Bay Rd');
addMarker(38.967567, -123.115883,'<b>9714</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 900ft south of Mountain House Rd');
addMarker(38.96645, -123.115501,'<b>9715</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 1300ft south of Mountain House Rd');
addMarker(39.748081, -121.897346,'<b>9717</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 32, 160ft west of Regent Ln');
addMarker(39.745018, -121.889984,'<b>9718</b><br/>North Side of Hwy 32, 475ft west of Indigo Ln');
addMarker(39.508083, -121.493301,'<b>9720</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 162 (Olive Hwy), 75ft east of Ward Blvd');
addMarker(39.697567, -122.206047,'<b>9721</b><br/>West Side of I-5, 245ft north of Road 25 (3 miles south of Orland)');
addMarker(40.306316, -122.278984,'<b>9722</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 436ft north of Valley Auction Rd (apprx 9 miles north of Red Bluff)');
addMarker(39.699051, -121.782265,'<b>9723</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 365ft south of Southgate Ct');
addMarker(40.662418, -118.129768,'<b>9801</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 1 mile east of Imlay Overcrossing');
addMarker(40.663868, -118.124519,'<b>9802</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 1.25 miles east of Imlay Exit');
addMarker(41.924084, -124.139633,'<b>9804</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 370ft north of Denny St (south of Smith River)');
addMarker(41.9524, -124.203781,'<b>9805</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 390ft north of Mouth of Smith River Rd');
addMarker(39.4272, -123.357498,'<b>9807</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 101, 1 mile north of Willits City limits');
addMarker(39.614216, -119.226814,'<b>9808</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 2000ft west of East Fernley Exit');
addMarker(40.192833, -118.448067,'<b>9809</b><br/>South Side of I-80, east of Lovelock East Exit MP 19.07');
addMarker(39.697819, -121.78112,'<b>9811</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 185ft south of Southgate Ct');
addMarker(40.950249, -117.494553,'<b>9812</b><br/>North Side of I-80, 1600ft west of Golconda Overcrossing');
addMarker(39.553467, -122.217529,'<b>9901</b><br/>West Side of I-5, 2 miles north of Willows I-5/Hwy 162 Interchange');
addMarker(36.000183, -119.300499,'<b>A042</b><br/>East Side of Hwy 99, 1.4 miles north of Avenue 104');
addMarker(35.651951, -119.221466,'<b>A043</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 1/2 mile north of Whisler Road');
addMarker(35.396015, -119.032051,'<b>A044</b><br/>South Side of Hwy 204, 3/4 mile west of F Street');
addMarker(35.420181, -119.061668,'<b>A045</b><br/>West Side of Hwy 99, 1/2 mile north of Olive Drive');
addMarker(35.339668, -119.033798,'<b>A046</b><br/>North Side of Ming Avenue, 300ft east of Castro Lane');
addMarker(35.383217, -119.072998,'<b>A047</b><br/>South Side of Rosedale Hwy (Hwy 58), 400ft east of Fruitvale');
addMarker(40.425983, -122.282166,'<b>ROB1</b><br/>East Side of I-5, .85 miles south of Deschutes Rd Overcrossing');
addMarker(40.402817, -122.281265,'<b>SOV1</b><br/>East Side of I-5, 5000ft north of Gas Point Rd');
 }
 </script>

 </head>
 <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
 <div id="map"></div>
 </html>
```

Comment: What does the code the browser sees look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map doesn't have a size.  You have this in your css:

```
#map_canvas { height: 100%; }
```

However your "map" div has id "map".  That should be:

```
#map { height: 100%; }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hj4tyd73/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
  new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
var center = null;
var map = null;
var currentPopup;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
  var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  bounds.extend(pt);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pt,
    icon: icon,
    map: map
  });
  var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: info,
    maxWidth: 300
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    if (currentPopup != null) {
      currentPopup.close();
      currentPopup = null;
    }
    popup.open(map, marker);
    currentPopup = popup;
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
    map.panTo(center);
    currentPopup = null;
  });
}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    }
  });

  $name = 'New York';
  $lat = 40.7127837;
  $lon = -74.0059413;
  $desc = 'New York, NY';
  addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>' + $name + '</b><br/>' + $desc);

  $name = 'Newark';
  $lat = 40.735657;
  $lon = -74.1723667;
  $desc = 'Newark, NJ';
  addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>' + $name + '</b><br/>' + $desc);

  center = bounds.getCenter();
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are making the center of the map 0,0. Try initializing the map with a center value of latlgn.

Comment: Great catch! I added some real coords, but unfortunately the map is still not displaying.

Comment: This isn't going to help fix your problem, but in js, you dont need if "(x != null)".  you can just say "if(x)". Sounds nitpicky, but its one of the good parts about javascript.

Comment: I don't see the problem - as geocode suggested before, try to narrow it down to what is absolutely essential (make the map appear on the screen with a pin) - then integrate that example into your system.